# For a STM32, can I use a quad SPI and SD card as a framebuffer for a LTDC LCD driver?

Tags: stm32, lcd, tft

I'm using STM32F756

The SD card is 20 MHz and I know the performance would suck for an 800 x 480 display, but will the hardware do it? Or is RAM the only medium required?

I screwed up, have no external RAM and there's not enough internal RAM.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Just what kind of performance do you need? Real-time data? Slow changing data? Motion graphics? Animation?

Comment: What controller does your display have? A link to the datasheet would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> The SD card is 20 MHz and I know the performance would suck for an 800 x 480 display, but will the hardware do it?

No. The LCD driver needs to be able to access its framebuffer as memory. SDIO isn't memory-mapped, and QSPI won't drive an SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.  The SD card might be fast enough for burst transfers, but it does not provide deterministic worst case access for the data which is required to drive a frame buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the read/write speed would match. You would rapidly exceed read/write cycles!

-> No